# API Gateway with Lambda non-proxy integration

Tags: api, aws-lambda, mapping, aws-api-gateway, vtl

I am new to AWS API Gateway, hence I am struggling even with a simple app as the one below. I have a DynamoDB table as below:

[image]

I have created a REST API with a Lambda/proxy integration. I have defined a resource named "/query " and a GET method. The Lambda function Python code is shown below.

```
import json
import boto3
from boto3.dynamodb.conditions import Key

mydb=boto3.resource('dynamodb',region_name='us-east-1')
table=mydb.Table('catula')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    #query_name=event['catName']
    query_name=event['queryStringParameters']['catName']
    response=table.query(KeyConditionExpression=Key('catName').eq(query_name))['Items']
    
    #print(response)
    
    return {
        "statusCode": 200,
        "body": json.dumps(response)
            }
```

I deploy the API as dev and when I invoke the dev stage with the proper query string, either on a new browser window or with Postman,

```
https://km7nniniyc.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev/query?catName=bella
```

I get the desired response,

```
[
    {
        "isFeral": "true",
        "color": "calico",
        "age": "2",
        "catName": "bella"
    }
]
```

Now, I am trying to replicating with Lambda non-proxy.

On Method Request / URL Query String Parameters I define

[image]

and on Integration Request / Mapping Templates I define

[image]

Before I even deploy to a stage, I test the GET Method Execution with {query} catName=bella and I get the following Response Body (I intentionally do not include the Response Headers and Logs so I do not cram this question - I hope you get the idea):

[image]

I know the error or omission I am doing is something rather basic and simple. Yet, after 72 hrs I regret to admit that I am at a loss. Any help would be most appreciated.

Thanks in advance from Theodoros.

Comment: The first thing you need to do is add a `print(event)` as the first line of your Lambda handler function. Then you can see in the logs exactly what is being passed into your function. I'm pretty sure `queryStringParemeters` is incorrect, since you are doing a custom parameter mapping, but if you just logged the event you would be able to see that clearly for yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line of your code

```
query_name=event['queryStringParameters']['catName']
```

is looking for queryStringParameters in event.  However, your custom request mapping template has already read the query parameters and created a key catName with a value.  So you are getting a key error because there is no key queryStringParameters.  This line of your code, which is commented out, looks more correct.

```
#query_name=event['catName']
```

Mark is correct, add a print(event) at the start of your lamda and turn on logging for your lamda.  You can also run a lambda or an API test in the console.  In the logs you will see what is being passed in.

Comment: RodP and Mark B. Thank you guys! I upvoted both your responses. I did exactly as instructed with the print statement and it shed light. Also, your explanation about "your custom request mapping template has already read the query parameters and created a key catName with a value" was most educative.  The correct line of code is

Comment: "query_string=event['catName']". Though, I cannot understand why then Lambda proxy integration also works with the line of code including the 'queryStringParameters'. Any idea?

Comment: Sorry I am not that familiar with proxy vs non-proxy but it must be altering how/what is passed to your handler.